# What is automorphism group of this iso-regular graph?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group

Given the iso-regular graph below, I am interested in finding the automorphism of the graph given below.$$AUT(X) = \{\sigma \mid X^{\sigma} = X\}$$

[image]
To me it appears that all possible bijections are going to be there so, $n!$ many elements will be there.

Comment: It's certainly not going to be $20!$. As soon as you make a choice for $\sigma(1)$, this will restrict your choices for all vertices which are adjacent to $1$.

Comment: So for  one block of 4 vertices, is it 20 . 2 . 2 . 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If we shrink each of the squares to a single vertex, we obtain $K_5$, which has $S_5$ as symmetry group. Now "un-shrink", and the position of the vertices within the squares is determined by where their adjacent other square is.
But not all of $S_5$ is allowed: Once we fix the position of square $1-2-3-4$, this square only allows $D_8$ symmetries.

In other words, we can move square $1-2-3-4$ to any of the five squares and then apply any of the eight symmmetries of the square to it.

Comment: I do not understand this argument. Are you considering the action on the five 4-cycles in the graph? I agree that this action is transitive (rotation shows that), but I don't think that is the entire group, since I believe the inner 10-cycle can be mapped to the outer 10-cycle.

Comment: @JeremyDover Yes, by roting the 1234 square by 180°, for example, the 10-cycles are swapped. Meanwhile I am getting confused whether rotating said square by 90° is even allowed (extendable to a graph auto) ... Is it only $D_4\rtimes C_5$ after all?

Comment: There is no subgroup of $S_5$ of the form $C_5\rtimes D_4$. (There isn't even a subgroup of that order.)

The arguments so far show that the group is a subgroup of $S_5$, containing a $D_5$ as a subgroup of index between $2$ and $4$ (In fact, dividing $4$ and divisible by $2$). The only such subgroup is $AGL(1,5)\cong C_5\rtimes C_4$.

In which case, the group acts regularly, so this is a Cayley graph on $AGL(1,5)$ (even a so-called graphical regular representation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to see that the group is regular on vertices. If you fix a vertex, you fix the unique vertex that is opposite it on the 4-cycle, and the unique vertex that is adjacent to it by an edge not on a 4-cycle. Now, these two type of relations induce a 2-valent graph on the set of vertices, and one can check that it is a 20-cycle.
(1-5-7-13-15-17-19-8-6-9-11-18-20-2-4-10-12-14-16-3-1)

Thus, only the identity fixes any vertex, and the group has order dividing 20.

Now, there is an obvious action of the dihedral group of order $10$, that is visible in the picture and, as Jeremy pointed out, you can also exchange the inner and outer cycle. So the automorphism group must have order 20. (And be isomorphic to $AGL(1,5)$, since it embeds in $S_5$.)